# Generic type in class declaration from generic type

Tags: java, class

The title it's a bit confusing, you will understand when you see my classes declarations.

I have an abstract class with a generic type

```
public abstract class BaseFoo<T>
```

And another class with a generic type that extends from that class

```
BaseBar<P extends BaseFoo>
```

What I would like is to acces the generic type from `BaseFoo` inside `BaseBar`, for example:

```
BaseBar<P extends BaseFoo<T>> {
    T mVar;
```

Although the previous declaration is incorrect, at least that says my IDE :P
I could achive that with something like this:

```
BaseBar<T, P extends BaseFoo<T>>
```

But it looks redundant for me, I would like to know if there was a way without having to declare the generic type in both classes.

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the same, I searched a lot before posting but it's tricky to make this questions

Answer (score 1):

It's not redundant to say:

```
BaseBar<T, P extends BaseFoo<T>>
```

You need to declare `T` in the type of `BaseBar` if you want to propagate it to `BaseFoo`. If you left `BaseFoo` without a type, then it's raw and your compiler cannot help you anymore.

Comment: But if I declare a class for example: `BaseFooImpl extends BaseFoo<Integer>` and `BaseBarImpl extends BaseBar<BaseFooImpl>`, is it not redundant to say: `BaseBarImpl extends BaseBar<Integer, BaseFooImpl>`